# set  NSURL  for download file from webserver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I want to download file from webserver, ok till now i know how to download it with NSURL intiwithstring;--this url is hardcoded
but now i need following:

1st i am reading path of file from webserver : 
path = c:/programfiles/yy/ss/file/result.zip

but now how to put this path as url to download this file.

i am really very much confused..
thank you in advance

Comment: Wait, wait. A Windows path as a URL??

Comment: No need to downvote;  this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: yes i have windows path and want as NSURL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a url. You can't just download non hosted files from a web server's local disk. Have whatever is returning you that local file path convert it to a url first and use that with NSURL.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion i was so much confused , i cant think of this but yes i will try for this n try to solve this thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

ok, here i figure it out

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:UrlForDownload];  
//and also i want to add "https/100.11.1..1"  to url

//so i convert url to string as i want to add "https/100.11.1..1"   
NSMutableString *s = [fileURL absoluteString];  

[sArray addObject:s];   
NSMutableString *ResultURL = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];  
for (NSMutableString *s1 in sArray)   
{  
  [ResultURL appendString:@"https/100.11.1..1/servicename/folderForDownloadFile/"];  
  [ResultURL appendString:s1];  
  [ResultURL appendString:@"/filenameToBeDownloaded.extension"];  

}    
//filenameToBeDownloaded- i know filename and extension as i am getting full path but not filename   

//folderForDownloadFile- this folder is hosted on IIS   
//and following just continue with url and urlrequest

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:ResultURL];  

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval: 60.0];
```